# How to enable correctly the Application Insight tracing on Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

unfortunately i'm not able to trace correctly my applications with Application Insight.

My Spring Boot project exposes a series of @HttpTriggers and @ServiceBusTriggers through the spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure library and below I will show you an example with two of these triggers (but the problem with application insight correlation exists on all of them): **HelloWorldProducerTrigger** and **FooProducerTrigger**.

First of all, I've imported the applicationinsights-agent library among the dependencies of my project and the maven-dependency-plugin configuration as defined in:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ApplicationInsights-Java-Samples/blob/main/maven/pom.xml

and subsequently inserted the prop APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING among the properties of my function, in the Configuration section.

After deploying the function I tried to call my HelloWorldProducerTrigger api (/api/v2/hello-world) which in turn calls the FooProducerTrigger api (api/v2/foo) via a POST but in the end to end dashboard of my application insight requests are not related to each other:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yhZc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Rtd.png)

Analyzing the headers of my requests I noticed that Azure injects the W3C TraceContext "traceparent" attribute into the headers of each request as defined in the standard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/distributed-trace-data, but we can see below that the traceparent of HelloWorldProducerTrigger:

**"traceparent":"00-6d2fe7dfd8e3458b4baf94eb9825cd3d-cdd14db2bf0f112f-00"
OperationId: 6d2fe7dfd8e3458b4baf94eb9825cd3d
ParentId: cdd14db2bf0f112f**

and that of FooProducerTrigger have a different operationId (so i think that the correlation problem is that)

**"traceparent":"00-5104fa229a07a7b3eeda5129ca1b7c66-4e4cb97be05bb545-00"
OperationId: 5104fa229a07a7b3eeda5129ca1b7c66
ParentId: 4e4cb97be05bb545**

What should I do to properly self-instrumentate my Spring Boot projects?

From the following guide I expected that once the applicationinsights-agent library was imported, my application would be self-instrumented and therefore I would see the correctly related calls on App Insight.

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=java

Thank you!

Comment: operation id comes from app insight/azure and is not the same as the trace id. "I've imported the applicationinsights-agent library" This is the old way, you should use the app insight agent jar along side the jar of your app when deployed (can be done in the pipeline instead of pom.xml), you need at least the connection string https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=java

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @paizo, I agree with him and also as per the MS documentation which I followed that you could check below.

> What should I do to properly self-instrumentate my Spring Boot projects?

You need to check that the `traceparent` headers are propagated correctly and consistently across the application components. In your case which you're seeing different `OperationId` values for different requests means that the correlation might not be set up correctly.

> From the following guide I expected that once the applicationinsights-agent library was imported, my application would be self-instrumented and therefore I would see the correctly related calls on App Insight.

Yes, it's true even if in my case I have created same scenario in my environment, and it works as-well.

[image]

- Here is the dependencies for Application Insights instrumentation, it involves adding the `applicationinsights-agent` dependency to your `pom.xml` file.

**Microsoft Application Insights Java Agent:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-Core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.19</version>
</dependency>
```

**HttpTrigger:**

[image]

**Servicebus Queue trigger:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Distributed tracing and telemetry correlation in Azure Application Insights.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/distributed-trace-data)

**Updated Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-agent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, thanks so much for replying! So you simply added the applicationinsights-core dependency and not the applicationinsights-agent? After adding the core dependency did you create any other configurations in the pom.xml or resources?

Comment: I worked on both configurations (agent and core as-well) [`applicationinsights-agent`](https://i.imgur.com/0OxmdJd.png) is the correct integration for my build and deployment process. there is no excess core dependency configuration in my pom.xml file.